# Find modulo of large number with large number

Tags: algorithm, math

I have a number `n` and `m`. They are both very large and exceed the limits of a C++ `long long`. How do i find `n mod m` accurately?

Naive `n % m` only works up to `2^63-1`, getting `9` on the online judge.

Adding one digit of `n` at a time and using `% m` works for small `m`, but is quite slow, and without hardcoding for the special case where `m = 1`, it exceeds the time limit on such a small `m`. It gets `37` on the online judge.

So is there a method of calculating `n mod m` given them as strings?

Problem: https://dunjudge.me/analysis/problems/669/

Comment: You haven't included all the details of the question. As you've written it, the answer is "use a bignum library". But you are given in the constraints section of the question that m is expressed as the product of numbers between 1 to 10, and is less than 10!. That constraint makes the problem a bit easier to write your own.

Answer (score 1):

Given that `m` is constrained to be less than 10! (which is 3628800) you can process the digits of `n` one at a time in an easy way.

If the digits of `n` are `d[i]` where `i` goes from 0 to `N-1` (with `d[0]` being the most significant digit), then something like this works (pseudocode):

```
R = 0
for i = 0 to N-1
    R = (10 * R + d[i]) % m
return R
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to handle this is the binary approach. Algorithm steps would go like this:

1. Set `a = n` shift `a` to left as much as possible while still `m > a`
2. `m = m - a`
3. If `m < n` DONE result is in m, Else go to step 1

For first step, since you have both numbers in strings, finding the index of the first `1`from left for both `m` and `n` and taking their difference would give the necessary number of shifts.

I haven't implemented it, however all operations are basic binary ops (avoids relatively costly modulo) and algorithm's complexity is O(N) where N is the number of digits; so it should have a nice performance.